# Can't run built SFML project from Xcode template

Tags: xcode, macos, sfml

I've downloaded **SFML-2.6.1** and created Xcode project from template on my **M1 Mac**. Although project is building, it can not run, raising this error in the **Xcode** terminal:

```
dyld[7793]: Library not loaded: @rpath/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system
  Referenced from: <1E3396AD-BA26-30F7-9B22-99E9329A24A5> /Users/zolars/Library/
Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RayMarching-ahreigxcnvvlrmauhbbbcgvxsxku/Build/Products/Debug/RayMarching.app/Contents/MacOS/RayMarching
  Reason: tried: '/Users/zolars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RayMarching-ahreigxcnvvlrmauhbbbcgvxsxku/
Build/Products/Debug/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file), 
'/Users/zolars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RayMarching-ahreigxcnvvlrmauhbbbcgvxsxku/
Build/Products/Debug/RayMarching.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file), 
'/Users/zolars/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RayMarching-ahreigxcnvvlrmauhbbbcgvxsxku/
Build/Products/Debug/RayMarching.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.6.1/sfml-system' (no such file)
```

I searched internet about similar errors but without any luck so far.
Can anybody help me?